# Why is my beautiful soup scraper returning no text? The script doesnt throw an error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

#scraping ESPN

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.espn.com/womens-college-basketball/scoreboard/_/date/20221107').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

game = soup.find('ul', class_= "ScoreCell__Competitors").text

[enter image description here][1]print(game)
```

#the text "Cleveland State" should be returned. I am a web scraping novice, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `.text` attribute of that element was empty, so it printed a blank string.  (That webpage likely uses javascript to dynamically create page content.  But `requests` does not understand javascript, so that's why the text was blank)

Comment: You'll probably have to fetch the page content with something that acts more like a real browser and can process javascript, like Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Selenium with chrome

Download [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) and [Chromedrive](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Install selenium

`pip install selenium`

```
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = '/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Get the element using your class name using the driver

`h1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ScoreCell__Competitors')`